# org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, ignite

I have a project with Spring Boot and Ignite. Everything works as long as I use the default configuration provided for Spring. However, the default behavior is in-memory database and I'd like to activate the Ignite Persistence so that I write records on disk in addition to have cache, which shouldn't be hard.

I checked the `IgniteAutoConfiguration.java` and based on that I wrote this class:

```
@Configuration
public class IgniteManualConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ignite")
    public IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration(IgniteConfigurer configurer) {
        IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();

        //data storage configuration
        DataStorageConfiguration storageCfg = new DataStorageConfiguration();
        storageCfg.getDefaultDataRegionConfiguration().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
        cfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(storageCfg);

        configurer.accept(cfg);
        return cfg;
    }
}
```

It's the exact same as the auto-configuration implementation but with an additional storage configuration.

Well, my app doesn't start anymore unfortunately. This is the stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'queryController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'topic2MongoCollection'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'topic2MongoCollection': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'databaseFacade'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'igniteFacade': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ignite'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ignite' defined in class path resource [org/apache/ignite/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/IgniteAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.Ignite]: Factory method 'ignite' threw exception; nested exception is class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:64) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at com.***.Application.main(Application.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'topic2MongoCollection': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'databaseFacade'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'igniteFacade': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ignite'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ignite' defined in class path resource [org/apache/ignite/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/IgniteAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.Ignite]: Factory method 'ignite' threw exception; nested exception is class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'igniteFacade': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ignite'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ignite' defined in class path resource [org/apache/ignite/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/IgniteAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.Ignite]: Factory method 'ignite' threw exception; nested exception is class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ignite' defined in class path resource [org/apache/ignite/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/IgniteAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.Ignite]: Factory method 'ignite' threw exception; nested exception is class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.ignite.Ignite]: Factory method 'ignite' threw exception; nested exception is class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:1089) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:331) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.IgniteAutoConfiguration.ignite(IgniteAutoConfiguration.java:99) ~[ignite-spring-boot-autoconfigure-ext-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.IgniteAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f1b3b34.CGLIB$ignite$2(<generated>) ~[ignite-spring-boot-autoconfigure-ext-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.IgniteAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f1b3b34$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c29139f4.invoke(<generated>) ~[ignite-spring-boot-autoconfigure-ext-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.apache.ignite.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.IgniteAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7f1b3b34.ignite(<generated>) ~[ignite-spring-boot-autoconfigure-ext-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1407) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2052) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1698) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1114) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:634) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:560) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:328) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    ... 71 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 2
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.io.IOVersions.forVersion(IOVersions.java:87) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.io.PageIO.getPageIO(PageIO.java:665) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.tree.io.PageIO.getPageIO(PageIO.java:629) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.metastorage.MetaStorage.getOrAllocateMetas(MetaStorage.java:523) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.metastorage.MetaStorage.initInternal(MetaStorage.java:250) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.metastorage.MetaStorage.init(MetaStorage.java:167) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.createMetastorage(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:1098) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.readMetastore(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:875) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.persistence.GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.notifyMetaStorageSubscribersOnReadyForRead(GridCacheDatabaseSharedManager.java:5022) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1251) ~[ignite-core-2.9.1.jar:2.9.1]
    ... 77 common frames omitted
```

This error message doesn't give me any information about where the problem is from my point of view.

Comment: Could you please share a whole application that you are trying to run with autoconfiguration plugin for Apache Ignite? Have you disabled the default configuration and did you try to modify existing configuration as the example states?

https://github.com/apache/ignite-extensions/tree/master/modules/spring-boot-autoconfigure-ext/examples

Comment: https://github.com/Giovarco/ignite-demo

Comment: If you run it on IntelliJ like I do, make sure to set Java 11.0.2 otherwise you'll get a different error message